# how to merge column with tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, merge

I want the columns of the last row to be merged to one. How to do it? When i am having long sentence it wont come to next line even if i use \newline. Could anyone help me by adding one more such row...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{paralist}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!b]
        \centering
        
        
        
        \caption{ Comparison between ST-Kriging, Bayesian inference, and ANNs.}
        \label{tab:2}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \scriptsize
        
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
            
            \hline
            \textbf{} & \textbf{Bayesian Inferences} & \textbf{ST-Kriging} & \textbf{ANNs}  \\ \hline
            \textbf{Computational Complexity}   & NP-hard \cite{ref-satria2020spatial} & $O(N^2)$ & $O(i\times o\times n + n\times o)$ or $O(n \times o \times (i+1))$ for training a single epoch. \cite{ref-taylor1995freeway} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Performance Evaluation }  & Provides a posterior probability distribution with confidence interval.  & 
            Ensure linear unbiased predictors. & Epoch with the lowest sum of squared error.\\ \hline
            \textbf{Weaknesses}   & Very computationally intensive due to choosing the proper prior distribution. 
            & 
            
            \begin{compactitem}
                \item Missing value causes error in unmatched dimensions.
                \item Can not handle large datasets.
                \item Require normal distribution.
            \end{compactitem} 
            
            &
            Require intensive data training, and this might lead to an overfitting problem. \\ \hline
            \textbf{Strengths }  
            & 
            \begin{compactitem}
                
                \item Handle large and small data. 
                \item Handle missing values.
                \item Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
                
            \end{compactitem}
            &
            \begin{itemize} 
                \item Handle small data.
                \item Computational efficiency.
            \end{itemize}
            &
            
            \begin{compactitem}
                \item Handle big data and small data.
                \item Accommodate missing values without a separate estimation step [108]
                \item Computational efficiency due to the parallelity feature.
                \item Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
            \end{compactitem}
            \\ \hline
            \textbf{Overcoming the Limitation}   
            &
            Use uninformative prior to reduce the computational time, however, it can affect the prediction accuracy negatively.
            &
            Remove observations that include missing values.  
            & 
            \begin{compactitem}
                
                \item Decrease the number of layers of the network.
                
                \item  Use iterative methods to stop the training process such as gradient descent.
            \end{compactitem}
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        
        
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What should be content in the merged columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For last two rows you need to form multi column cells. At "classic" table by use suggestion in @cabohah answer, or as is suggested below by use of the `tabullaray` package syntax (see both MWEs below)
- It is unclear what should be content of last two rows.
- Please edit your question and clarify this.

So, the following MWE is mostly off-topic with suggestion how to simplify your table code and make table nicer. In this context for your table I would use:

- `tabularray` package instead of the `tabularx` for table (it enable simple syntax for inserting and make nice looking lists)
- `enumitem` package instead of `paralist` for better formatting list in table

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}   % ?
%\usepackage{microtype}              % ?

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{ Comparison between ST-Kriging, Bayesian inference, and ANNs.}
    \label{tab:2}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep = 4pt,
             colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{3}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight]}},
             measure = vbox,
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, m, cmd=\Centering},
             rowsep  = 5pt,
             stretch = -1,
             hspan=minimal,
             cell{Y,Z}{1} = {c=4}{font=\normalfont} % define multi column cells in the last two rows
             }             
    &   {Bayesian\\ Inferences} 
        &   ST-Kriging  
            &   ANNs            \\
%
{Computational\\ Complexity}
    &   NP-hard \cite{ref-satria2020spatial}
        &   $O(N^2)$
            &   $O(i\times o\times n + n\times o)$ or $O(n \times o \times (i+1))$ for training a single epoch. \cite{ref-taylor1995freeway}
                                \\
{Performance\\ Evaluation}
    &   Provides a posterior probability distribution with confidence interval.
        &   Ensure linear unbiased predictors.
            &   Epoch with the lowest sum of squared error.
                                \\
Weaknesses
    &   Very computationally intensive due to choosing the proper prior distribution.
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item   Missing value causes error in unmatched dimensions.
        \item   Can not handle large datasets.
        \item   Require normal distribution.
            \end{itemize}   
            &   Require intensive data training, and this might lead to an overfitting problem.
                            \\
Strengths
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   Handle large and small data.
    \item   Handle missing values.
    \item   Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
        \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Handle small data.
            \item   Computational efficiency.
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Handle big data and small data.
                \item   Accommodate missing values without a separate estimation step [108]
                \item   Computational efficiency due to the parallelity feature.
                \item   Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
                    \end{itemize}
                                \\
{Overcoming\\ the Limitation}
    &   Use uninformative prior to reduce the computational time, however, it can affect the prediction accuracy negatively.
        &   Remove observations that include missing values.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Decrease the number of layers of the network.
                \item   Use iterative methods to stop the training process such as gradient descent.
                    \end{itemize}
                                \\
Penultimate table row has merged cells of all columns. It is unclear what is contents of this row.
    &   &   &               \\
Last row has merged cells. It is unclear what is contents of this row.
    &   &   &               \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout. You may consider to change it by use of the `geometry` package)

**Addendum:**
For more professional looks if table I would remove the most of table rule. For used on I would use rules as are defined in the `booktabs` package (loaded by `booktabs` library):

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs

%\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}   % ?
\usepackage{microtype}               % used for better inter words spacing

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,   % load the package of the same name
                varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison between ST-Kriging, Bayesian inference, and ANNs.}
    \label{tab:2}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 4pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{3}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight]} @{}},
             measure = vbox,
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, m, cmd=\Centering},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 5pt},
             stretch = -1,
             hspan=minimal,
             cell{Y,Z}{1} = {c=4}{font=\normalfont}
             }
    \toprule
    &   {Bayesian\\ Inferences}
        &   ST-Kriging
            &   ANNs            \\
    \midrule
{Computational\\ Complexity}
    &   NP-hard \cite{ref-satria2020spatial}
        &   $O(N^2)$
            &   $O(i\times o\times n + n\times o)$ or $O(n \times o \times (i+1))$ for training a single epoch. \cite{ref-taylor1995freeway}
                                \\
{Performance\\ Evaluation}
    &   Provides a posterior probability distribution with confidence interval.
        &   Ensure linear unbiased predictors.
            &   Epoch with the lowest sum of squared error.
                                \\
Weaknesses
    &   Very computationally intensive due to choosing the proper prior distribution.
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item   Missing value causes error in unmatched dimensions.
        \item   Can not handle large datasets.
        \item   Require normal distribution.
            \end{itemize}
            &   Require intensive data training, and this might lead to an overfitting problem.
                            \\
Strengths
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   Handle large and small data.
    \item   Handle missing values.
    \item   Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
        \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item   Handle small data.
            \item   Computational efficiency.
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Handle big and small data.
                \item   Accommodate missing values without a separate estimation step [108]
                \item   Computational efficiency due to the parallelity feature.
                \item   Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
                    \end{itemize}
                                \\
{Overcoming\\ the Limitation}
    &   Use uninformative prior to reduce the computational time, however, it can affect the prediction accuracy negatively.
        &   Remove observations that include missing values.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Decrease the number of layers of the network.
                \item   Use iterative methods to stop the training process such as gradient descent.
                    \end{itemize}
                                \\
Penultimate table row contain the cell composed from merged cells from all columns. It is unclear what is contents of this row. Therefore in it is temporary used just dummy text filler:

\lipsum[66]
    &   &   &               \\
Last row has merged cells too. The contents of this row is unknown.
    &   &   &               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This code really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you expect. To merge four columns of a row of your `tabularx`, you can use `\multicolumn{4}{|p{\dimexpr\hsize-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{…}`, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}% Because of using \caption above the tabular.

\usepackage{paralist}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!b]
        \centering
        
        
        
        \caption{ Comparison between ST-Kriging, Bayesian inference, and ANNs.}
        \label{tab:2}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \scriptsize
        
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
            
            \hline
            \textbf{} & \textbf{Bayesian Inferences} & \textbf{ST-Kriging} & \textbf{ANNs}  \\ \hline
            \textbf{Computational Complexity}   & NP-hard \cite{ref-satria2020spatial} & $O(N^2)$ & $O(i\times o\times n + n\times o)$ or $O(n \times o \times (i+1))$ for training a single epoch. \cite{ref-taylor1995freeway} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Performance Evaluation }  & Provides a posterior probability distribution with confidence interval.  & 
            Ensure linear unbiased predictors. & Epoch with the lowest sum of squared error.\\ \hline
            \textbf{Weaknesses}   & Very computationally intensive due to choosing the proper prior distribution. 
            & 
            
            \begin{compactitem}
                \item Missing value causes error in unmatched dimensions.
                \item Can not handle large datasets.
                \item Require normal distribution.
            \end{compactitem} 
            
            &
            Require intensive data training, and this might lead to an overfitting problem. \\ \hline
            \textbf{Strengths }  
            & 
            \begin{compactitem}
                
                \item Handle large and small data. 
                \item Handle missing values.
                \item Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
                
            \end{compactitem}
            &
            \begin{itemize} 
                \item Handle small data.
                \item Computational efficiency.
            \end{itemize}
            &
            
            \begin{compactitem}
                \item Handle big data and small data.
                \item Accommodate missing values without a separate estimation step [108]
                \item Computational efficiency due to the parallelity feature.
                \item Prior knowledge about uncertain input is not required.
            \end{compactitem}
            \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|p{\dimexpr\hsize-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{%
            \textbf{Overcoming the Limitation}
              
            Use uninformative prior to reduce the computational time, however, it can affect the prediction accuracy negatively.

            Remove observations that include missing values.  

            \begin{compactitem}
                
                \item Decrease the number of layers of the network.
                
                \item  Use iterative methods to stop the training process such as gradient descent.
            \end{compactitem}}
            \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        
        
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: last row is one column]

Comment: Code worked for me. It was really helpful.